# Proving equivalence between circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

[On page  E-3, example E.3](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/static/companion.websites/9780199339136/Appendices/Appendix_E.pdf)

In the example the author has asked us to prove that the two circuits are equivalent. On searching I found that circuits are considered to be equivalent if they have the same I-V characteristics. But how do I prove that they have the same I-V characteristics? On paper without any simulation.

Comment: I think he expects you to use  Thévenin’s theorem to reduce a complex network to it's equivalent cct.

Comment: This is a homework question, and we do not do others homework for them. Show some effort at solving the problem. Look at Tony Stewart's comment. Work it out on paper and show us your results, then we will try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should know a set of operations you can use to transform one circuit (consisting of linear circuit elements and current/voltage sources) into another equivalent circuit.

E.g.

- equivalent resistance of two resistors in parallel
- equivalent resistance of two resistors in series
- \$\Delta\$Y-equivalents
- Thevenin/Norton equivalent of voltage/current sources
- equivalence of circuit containing multiple sources to circuit having only one source (superposition principle)

Any combination of such transformations turn your starting circuit into another equivalent circuit. If you can find a combinations of transformations that get's you to the desired circuit (using your creativity and/or experience) you have proofed that they are equivalent.